# How to Determine Which Pivot Item is Navigated To Most Often

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am using a Pivot Control which contains 5 Pivot Items on a page. The user can only swipe right or left to get to these, but from the starting pivot, index = 0, I'd like to be able to determine which direction, and how far in that direction, a user generally goes. Since each of my pivots is loading several pieces of data, and the user can swipe either left or right from the starting index, my ultimate goal is to determine how often a user goes in either direction, and how far, and load those pivot items first. For Instance, If my pivots are

MainPage.xaml

```
<phone:Pivot x:Name="myPivot">
    <phone:PivotItem Header="one"/>
    <phone:PivotItem Header="two"/>
    <phone:PivotItem Header="three"/>
    <phone:PivotItem Header="four"/>
    <phone:PivotItem Header="five"/>
</phone:Pivot>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await RenderAsync();
    }

private async Task RenderAsync()
    {
        if (!Busy)
        {
            Busy = true;

            int side = 136;

            try
            {
                using (Bitmap bitmap = await App.Model.RenderBitmapAsync(side))
                {
                    if (Settings.LoadDynamically.Value == false)
                    {
                        await RenderAsync(bitmap, side, App.Model.One, OneWrapPanel);
                        await RenderAsync(bitmap, side, App.Model.Two, TwoWrapPanel);
                        await RenderAsync(bitmap, side, App.Model.Three, ThreeWrapPanel);
                        await RenderAsync(bitmap, side, App.Model.Four, FourWrapPanel);
                        await RenderAsync(bitmap, side, App.Model.Fiv, FiveWrapPanel);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Custom order goes here, load best order
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                NavigationService.GoBack();
            }

            Busy = false;
        }
    }
```

where the first pivot item is index of 0 and the fifth is index of 4, from the first pivot I'd like to be able to determine how many times the user navigates to pivot 5 (to the left) and to pivot two (the right). From here, I'd again like to know how many times the user keeps going in that direction. So if the user went to 5 and then 4, and also from two to three. Once this data is gathered, I'd like to be able to determine, possibly by setting some sort of weight for each situation, the best order to load each pivot item.

Comment: you have to write logic there is no analytics for this

Comment: I know, I guess what i'm asking is advice or a method to do this. I believe I can write the logic but I'm not sure of the best way to go about it to best accomplish the goal.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way, I think. It's very easy:

```
private void appPivot_LoadedPivotItem(object sender, PivotItemEventArgs e)
{
  startUse = DateTime.Now;
}

private void appPivot_UnloadingPivotItem(object sender, PivotItemEventArgs e)
{
  TimeSpan pivotUsage = DateTime.Now - startUse;
  // Save it somewhere regarding to SelectedPivotItem
}
```

But changing the order isn't recommended in the metro design guidance(as I remember), however I personally think that it's a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. I don't necessarily want to change the order of the pivot items, just the order that they are loaded based on most common navigation as described in my original post. I added some code as well to show you my current implementation.

Comment: How user will fly over the unloaded pivots? They all will be loaded in any case.

Comment: Well they wouldn't. I just want to make it seem to the user that the pivots are loading faster, by  loading the ones they navigate to more frequently before loading less frequently navigated pivots. Like perhaps load pivots one and two, then five, then three, and then four. Maybe this is a bad idea and I should just skip over pivots that haven't been loaded yet as you suggest. If I did do the skip method, how would that work?

Comment: I think it will be better to change the items order, it will work better for users that skipping.